# Jquery Rails Validation On Dynamically Generated Text Box Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have the following list that is dynamically generated.  I would like the ability to do some Simple Jquery validation if the qty input for a product is less than the qty available, I would like to alert the user.  The event I would like to use would most likely be the .change() event because I want the validation to occur before the user attempts to submit the form.  The problem I'm having is I need a catch all solution since the id's are dynamically driven. Not sure where to start.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <input class="shipment_qty_field" id="qty_product_1" type="text" />
  </li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li id ="avail_qty_product_1></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input class="shipment_qty_field" id="qty_product_2" type="text" />
  </li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li id="avail_qty_product_2"></li>
</ul>   
<ul>
  <li>
    <input class="shipment_qty_field" id="qty_product_3" type="text" />
  </li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li id="avail_qty_product_3"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried the client_side_validations gem?

Comment: No I sure haven't.  For learning purposes, I'd like to do it in jQuery.

Comment: Looking at the gem I don't think it will work due to complexity of this being a many to many (has_many :through) relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take all your li's with id = "avail_qty_product_xx" and stick the value in the li that holds the input tag as an 'data-qty' such as:

`<li class="qty_container" data-qty="3">
    <input class="shipment_qty_field" type="text" />
  </li>`

Then you can add a change handler for the li

`$('li.qty_container input').change(function() {
  threshold = parseInt($(this).closest('li').data('qty'))
   if(parseInt($(this).val()) > threshold) {
      alert('threshold exceeded!')
   }
})`

Comment: This works great.  The only thing that I needed to change is instead of $(this).closest('li').data('qty') I used $(this).data('qty') as closest returned nothing.